# Google Maps DistanceMatrix

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google API, what I need to do is get two different distances in miles. At the moment I have the following:-

```
var start = arrObjLatLngs[0];
var end = arrObjLatLngs[arrObjLatLngs.length - 1];

var base = new google.maps.LatLng(52.781048888889, -1.2110222222222546);

var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
  {
    origins: [base, base],
    destinations: [start, end],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);


function callback(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        var element = results[j];
        var distance = element.distance.text;
        var duration = element.duration.text;
        var from = origins[i];
        var to = destinations[j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I need to have is two variables; `$runinPickup` and `$runinDestination` that contains the distance between 1.) base and start (which will be $runinPickup) and 2.) base and end (which will be $runinDestination)

If I alert `distance` I get the response:-

13.9 km

5.2 km

13.9 km

5.2 km

Firstly, I'm just wanting to know how I can get the distance of just the distance between `base` and `start` as $runinPickup. Secondly, is there a way I can do this so it doesn't include the decimal? So instead of 13.9 km for the first value, it would just be 13.

Then I would need to convert it into miles, which I'm guessing once I can get the value I would do it as follows:

```
var pickup_distance = parseInt(($fieldPickup / 8) * 5); ?
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: After that line for travelMode add 'unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,' to get results in miles rather than k's

Comment: thanks Rafe, and how would I only be able to get a whole value as apposed to decimal? - also If the distance is very short, it comes up 1 metre, where as I would expect that to be 0 miles otherwise this will effect calculations

Comment: You could always try using parseInt on the result

Comment: perfect, thanks Rafe. Do you know how I could get these results as seperate values? At the moment if I alert distance it gives me 2 values. Basically I need the distance for base to start as $variable1 and base to end as a seperate value (as $variable2)

Comment: When you say it gives you two values, how? Are they in a comma sperated string, an array? what?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_results)?  Passing the same address twice in the origins array:

```
   origins: [base, base],
   destinations: [start, end],
```

Is going to give you the same result twice.  This should work (not tested), and give you 2 results:

```
   origins: [base],
   destinations: [start, end],
```

To get miles I would suggest setting the unitSystem to [IMPERIAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_units) (although I can't find a definition of what that means in the documentation):

```
unitSystem (optional) — The unit system to use when displaying distance. Accepted values are:

google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC (default)
google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
```

You can of course [convert METRIC units to miles](https://www.google.com/?q=meters+to+miles/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=meters+to+miles&oq=meters+to+miles).

[Example showing the two values](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_distance-matrixA.html), with distances in IMPERIAL units. Modified from the example in the documentation.

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var geocoder;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markersArray = [];

var base = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930385, -3.118425);
var start = 'Greenwich, England';
var destinationA = 'Stockholm, Sweden';
var end = new google.maps.LatLng(50.087692, 14.421150);

var destinationIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=D|FF0000|000000';
var originIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O|FFFF00|000000';

function initialize() {
  var opts = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.53, 9.4),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), opts);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  calculateDistances();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function calculateDistances() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [base],
    destinations: [start, end],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = '<table border="1">';
    deleteOverlays();
    var stringArray = ['$runinPickup', '$runinDestination'];
    var htmlString = '<table border="1">';
    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      addMarker(origins[i], false);
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        addMarker(destinations[j], true);
        htmlString += '<tr><td>' + stringArray[j] + '</td><td>' + results[j].distance.text + '</td></tr>';
        outputDiv.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + stringArray[j] + '</td><td>' + results[j].distance.text + '</td></tr>';
      }
    }
    htmlString += '</table>';
    // outputDiv.innerHTML += '</table>';
    outputDiv.innerHTML = htmlString;
    // alert(htmlString);
  }
}

function addMarker(location, isDestination) {
  var icon;
  if (isDestination) {
    icon = destinationIcon;
  } else {
    icon = originIcon;
  }
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': location
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon: icon
      });
      markersArray.push(marker);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function deleteOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: courier, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#map {
  height: 480px;
  width: 640px;
  border: solid thin #333;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and how would I just get the one result, i.e. distance for base to start as a seperate value

Comment: Your question was `what I need to do is get two different distances in miles`. I thought you wanted two results, has something changed?  If you only want one result, only pass in one argument in the destinations array also.

Comment: yeah sorry, I meant as seperate variables

Comment: Where do you need the variables? Is this in PHP (server side)?  As the DirectionsMatrix is asynchronous, you need to use the variables inside the callback routine (where you were "alerting" the distance).

Comment: i need them inside the callback function, at the moment, if I alert(distance); I get x and y, where as I want these as seperate values, ie variable1 = distance between base & start, and variable2 = distance between base and end.

Comment: if I echo(distance) I get two values, I want to echo(variable) and get 1 distance, and echo(variable2) and get the other distance.

Comment: so instead of one response containing both values, i want to seperate these responses into two different variables

Comment: Did you see my example which displays the two distances in a table?  That is accessing the two value when they are available.  Set your variables then (and do any processing required on them.