# Google Maps DistanceMatrix callback

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps Distance Matrix and what I need is two different distances,

at the moment I have the following:-

```
var start = arrObjLatLngs[0];
var end = arrObjLatLngs[arrObjLatLngs.length - 1];    
var base = new google.maps.LatLng(52.781048888889, -1.2110222222222546);

var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

service.getDistanceMatrix(
  {
    origins: [base],
    destinations: [start, end],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);


function callback(response, status) {

  if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {

    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {

      var results = response.rows[i].elements;

      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

        var element = results[j];
        var distance = Math.round(parseFloat(element.distance.text));
          alert(distance);
        var duration = element.duration.text;
        var from = origins[i];
        var to = destinations[j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I `alert($distance);` I get two responses, e.g. `15` and `10`

What I need is two seperate values, i.e. if I `alert($runinPickup);` I get `15` , if I alert `alert($runinDestination);` I get 10.

I thought they were in an array so I have tried `alert(distance[0])` but this comes back as undefined.

Do I have to do two seperate getDistanceMatrix requests or is there a way to seperate the two values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps DistanceMatrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413922/google-maps-distancematrix)

Comment: What about the answer to your previous question didn't you understand?  This question is identical, you should update your previous question with the new information, not create a new one.

Comment: as mentioned above, I am needing a seperate response for each distance instead of a variable which has both values

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Instead of alerting the distance, set your variable to the value.  Why can't you do that?