# Google distancematrix returning 4 results from 2 sets of orgins / destinations

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a travel calculator using the google distance matrix , I am trying to get distance calculations from point a to point b and then back from point b to point a. I would usually just add the two togther to get a total distance value, but because of one way streets and motorway junctions ect, one leg of the route may be longer than the other.

I am using the following code :

```
      getdistance:{
        options:{ 
          origins:["pe219px","ng323rj"], 
          destinations:["pe219px","ng323rj"],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
        },
        callback: function(results, status){
          var html = "";
          if (results){
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
              var elements = results.rows[i].elements;
              for(var j=0; j<elements.length; j++){
                switch(elements[j].status){
                  case "OK":
                  var sd=$(this).text();  
                    html += parseInt(elements[j].distance.text) + "<br />";
                    break;
                  case "NOT_FOUND":
                    html += "The origin and/or destination of this pairing could not be geocoded<br />";
                    break;
                  case "ZERO_RESULTS":
                    html += "No route could be found between the origin and destination.<br />";
                    break;
```

This gives me the result :

```
1
25
26
1
```

I am not sure where the 1's are coming from ?, I can see that 25 is there and 26 is back, but why are the ones there ?.

I have had a look at the following post :
[Google Maps DistanceMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413922/google-maps-distancematrix)

It suggests using :

```
origins: [base],
destinations: [start, end],
```

This returns :

```
25
1
```

I have also tried the start and end the other way round which gives me :

```
1
26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1's are for `pe219px` to `pe219px` and `ng323rj` to `ng323rj`.

The API didn't check if origins and destinations are equal, you will always get 
numberOfOrigins x numberOfDestinations results:

```
pe219px to pe219px 
pe219px to ng323rj
ng323rj to pe219px
ng323rj to ng323rj
```